# Tweak perl script for human-readable dmesg output

Tags: text-processing, perl, timestamps, dmesg

In RHEL 6 I have the kernel parameter:

```
printk.time=1
```

So that my dmesg would have a timestamp. However it shows in seconds from restart, like this:

```
[12.23456]
```

I found a script that you place inside .bashrc that converts the seconds to HR date.

```
dmesg_with_human_timestamps () {
$(type -P dmesg) "$@" | perl -w -e 'use strict;
    my ($uptime) = do { local @ARGV="/proc/uptime";<>}; ($uptime) = ($uptime =~ /^(\d+)\./);
    foreach my $line (<>) {
        printf( ($line=~/^\[\s*(\d+)\.\d+\](.+)/) ? ( "[%s]%s\n",  scalar localtime(time - $uptime + $1), $2 ) : $line )
    }'
}
alias dmesg=dmesg_with_human_timestamps
```

This works great and my dmesg output now looks like this:

```
[Fri Jun 10 13:07:14 2016]
```

But how can I change the code to make that look like this:

```
[2016/06/10 13:25:28]
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`POSIX` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/ext/POSIX/lib/POSIX.pod) includes the `strftime` function, which allows via `strftime(3)` conversion specifier characters the desired templating of time:

```
% perl -MPOSIX=strftime -E 'say strftime "[%F %T]", localtime(time)'
[2011-02-17 10:55:37]
%
```

So in your case make it `perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e ...` and then

```
printf( ($line=~/^\[\s*(\d+)\.\d+\](.+)/) ? ( "[%s]%s\n", strftime("%F %T", localtime(time - $uptime + $1)), $2 ) : $line )
```

You may need the more verbose `%Y-%m-%d %H...` template if your `strftime(3)` lacks `%F`, see `strftime(3)` for details.